# Not able to find the reference tab to add Json.NET for C#

Tags: c#, json

I created my first project and I am trying to work with JSON files. I am not able to see the tab of references in my Visual Studio. How can I retrieve the tab? I tried to Google and I cannot see the issue here.

This is my current Project Solution looks

[image]

[[image]]

[[image]]

Comment: add it from nuget

Comment: check the answers here - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e647dd93-0190-4d9d-adbf-aa347dc44abb/cant-see-quotreferencesquot-in-solution-explorer?forum=aspvisualstudio

Comment: its actually under dependencies now. Right click on it

Answer (score 1):

Double click the project node in Solution Explorer, add the following, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. After a few seconds the package is downloaded and installed.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You should also read up on using [NuGet package manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio) in Visual Studio.

Comment: Not the way I’d do it but hey if it works..  maybe add *where* to add it as project files are picky and brittle?

Comment: @stuartd agree, just thought this would get them going without having to deal with the conventional way for this time and hope they learn how to use either the command line tool or package manager in Visual Studio.

Comment: The nuget is downloaded but the acutal reference tab is not there, and the project does not find the reference of the newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: @Pablo_perico did you compile the project successfully then check to see if  Newtonsoft.Json.dll is in the debug folder?

Comment: @KarenPayne yes, I compiled it without no issues. I am calling a REST API and I am trying to work with the JSON. It is werid as I see other people having this reference tab but i do not. Even if I create another empty project.

Comment: @Pablo_perico Absence of a reference tab means you are working with a .NET Core SDK style project rather than a .NET classic Framework project.

Answer (score 0):

its here, right click on dependencies

[image]